# Firebase facebook login - very erratic

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, facebook-login, firebase-authentication

We are trying to use facebook login with Firebase in an Ionic app with the inappbrowser. It works fine on the browser (ionic serve) and fine in iOS (emulator and devices). However on android devices the login process is rather erratic. The callback doesn't get called on most tries (although strangely it works sometimes!). Upon enabling logging in firebase, I noticed that the browser tends to 'connect' and 'disconnect' multiple times. Here are the console logs from just clicking on the button that initiates the facebook login:

```
Facebook Popup initiation
p:0: Browser went online.  
p:0: Making a connection attempt  
c:0:4: Connection created  
c:0:4:0 Websocket connecting to wss://s-dal5-nss-23.firebaseio.com/.ws?v=5&ns=crisscross  
p:0: Browser went offline.  Killing connection.  
c:0:4: Closing realtime connection.  
c:0:4: Shutting down all connections  
c:0:4:0 WebSocket is being closed  
WebSocket connection to 'wss://s-dal5-nss-23.firebaseio.com/.ws?v=5&ns=crisscross' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.
c:0:4:0 WebSocket error.  Closing connection.  
c:0:4:0 Websocket connection was disconnected.  
p:0: data client disconnected  
0: onDisconnectEvents  
p:0: Browser went online.  
p:0: Making a connection attempt  
c:0:5: Connection created  
c:0:5:0 Connecting via long-poll to https://s-dal5-nss-23.firebaseio.com/.lp?start=t&ser=19709246&cb=3&v=5&ns=crisscross  
p:0: Browser went offline.  Killing connection.  
c:0:5: Closing realtime connection.  
c:0:5: Shutting down all connections  
c:0:5:0 Longpoll is being closed.  
p:0: data client disconnected  
0: onDisconnectEvents  
Long-poll script failed to load: https://s-dal5-nss-23.firebaseio.com/.lp?start=t&ser=19709246&cb=3&v=5&ns=crisscross 
p:0: Browser went online.  
p:0: Making a connection attempt  
c:0:6: Connection created  
c:0:6:0 Connecting via long-poll to https://s-dal5-nss-23.firebaseio.com/.lp?start=t&ser=57829348&cb=4&v=5&ns=crisscross  
c:0:6: Realtime connection established.  
p:0: connection ready  
p:0: {"r":37,"a":"auth","b":{"cred":"..."}}   
p:0: Listen on /users/facebook:... for default  
p:0: {"r":39,"a":"q","b":{"p":"/users/facebook:...","h":"pExrvNpPeLgfcNuQk/FRu4iWQrg="}}  
...
...
c:0:6: Primary connection is healthy.  
c:0:6:1 Websocket connecting to wss://s-dal5-nss-23.firebaseio.com/.ws?v=5&ns=crisscross&s=j9noKHDr1wjh5MiKjiKFIMxqNY2RvKoh  
p:0: Browser went offline.  Killing connection.  
c:0:6: Closing realtime connection.  
c:0:6: Shutting down all connections  
c:0:6:0 Longpoll is being closed.  
c:0:6:1 WebSocket is being closed  
WebSocket connection to 'wss://s-dal5-nss-23.firebaseio.com/.ws?v=5&ns=crisscross&s=j9noKHDr1wjh5MiKjiKFIMxqNY2RvKoh' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.
c:0:6:1 WebSocket error.  Closing connection.  
c:0:6:1 Websocket connection was disconnected.  
p:0: data client disconnected  
0: onDisconnectEvents  
Long-poll script failed to load: https://s-dal5-nss-23.firebaseio.com/.lp?id=1125523&pw=ma9Rk4SNwf&ser=53936…1qY3lPRFo5LlRaeTdjZXdMY09XRDZJWGFMOUZtNUFBcGQxTzBrVTVCNXloVHQ0cGVXTVkifX19 
Long-poll script failed to load: https://s-dal5-nss-23.firebaseio.com/.lp?id=1125523&pw=ma9Rk4SNwf&ser=53936342&ns=crisscross 
p:0: Authenticating using credential: eyJ0eX...fn81k
```

The logs don't have time stamps, but the whole thing above happened without any major delays in between, over 3-4 seconds.

I understand that it's trying to switch between long polling and some realtime connection (limited knowledge here), and that could explain why it goes offline and online. But so many times? And it ends up just not connecting.

Any idea anyone?

Comment: I am getting the same issue on android. Did you find a solution yet?

Comment: I can't remember our specific solution. If I remember correctly, we happened to move to a new firebase app and copy over our data, and it started to work. But we've moved to Parse now for quite a few other reasons.